Custom Audio Compression Media Foundation Implementation
The idea is to create a new Media Foundation Filter to be used in audio compression/decompression in media foundation MP4 sinkwriter/source reader. I plan to convert Facebook's Encodec into a MFT.
My problem is the sample descriptor.
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> ina = ...,myformat = ...;
    ina->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);
    ina->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, nch);
    ina->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, sr);
    int BA = (int)((br / 8) * nch);
    ina->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, (UINT32)(sr * BA));
    ina->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, BA);
    ina->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, br);
    ina->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);

    myformat->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
    myformat->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_myformat);
    myformat->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, nch);
    myformat->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, sr);
    hr = myformat->SetBlob(MF_MT_MPEG4_SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION, (UINT8*)cz, sizeof(cz));
    hr = myformat->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG4_CURRENT_SAMPLE_ENTRY,0);

    hr = wr->AddStream(myformat, &sidx);
    LogMediaType(myformat);

    hr = wr->SetInputMediaType(sidx, ina, 0);

This succeeds in the sink writer. After calling BeginWriting, I reset the sample description as I described in this related question:
        CComPtr<IMFMediaSink> pSink;
        CComPtr<IMFStreamSink> s2;
        CComPtr<IMFMediaTypeHandler> mth;
        CComPtr<IMFMediaType> mt2;
        wr->GetServiceForStream(MF_SINK_WRITER_MEDIASINK, GUID_NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSink));
        pSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &s2);
        s2->GetMediaTypeHandler(&mth);
        mth->GetCurrentMediaType(&mt2);
        LogMediaType(mt2);
        mt2->SetBlob(MF_MT_MPEG4_SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION, (UINT8*)cz, sizeof(cz));
        mt2->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG4_CURRENT_SAMPLE_ENTRY, 0);
        mth->SetCurrentMediaType(mt2);
        mt2 = 0;
        mth->GetCurrentMediaType(&mt2);
        LogMediaType(mt2);

Finalize() succeeds and I have an MP4. Now this MP4 cannot be read back with a source reader (not supported) and ffmpeg -i  shows
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: none (ecdc / 0x63646365), 48000 Hz, 0 channels, 288 kb/s (default)
.
This means that my problem is the sample descriptor, which currently is this:
UINT8 cz[100] = {
0x0,0x0,0x0,0x64, // len
0x73,0x74,0x73,0x64, // stsd
0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0, // verflag
0x0,0x0,0x0,0x1, // num
0x0,0x0,0x0,0x54, // len
'e','c','d','c', // code
0x0 (76 bytes)
    };

So obviously I must put something after the 'ecdc' string. What would that be?
Is this a form of, say, WAVEFORMATEX?
When I copy the data of an existing descriptor like AAC, the mp4 can be read and mediainfo/ffmpeg shows AAC/related info, which of course can't be played back because the stream is not AAC, but the file is parsed. However I wasn't able to find the source of this format.
What is the format I 'm supposed to provide as the box description?
I also found https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicktime-file-format/sound_sample_descriptions, perhaps it will help.

What you are doing sounds about right, the code fragments look okay. As it's not runnable it's hard to tell more. IMO what you should try is to instantiate MPEG-4 media source directly, the lowest level primitive (via source resolver) and feed it with your file. It might so happen that it can read it. But then Source Reader on top of this fails to recognize the format and you have an unreadable file.

@RomanRyltsov in this case other apps wont be able to use my decompressor. The idea is to publish a working codec for all apps.

My ponit is that it is not clear where exactly the problem right now, and you have to troubleshoot this as the description you provided is not sufficient.

The problem is in the descriptors, since if I put the AAC descriptor it works. My problem is how to fill the descriptor.
